# Is it possible in Android to launch a file using Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher if I have a content URI instead of a path?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace myNamespace
{
    class myClass
    {
        public async void OpenFile(string path)
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest("File", new ReadOnlyFile(path)));
        }
    }
}
```

It works well if `path` is a real file system path, and doesn't work if it is a URI, giving an error like:

> **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:** 'Could not find a part of the path "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/something".'

(I'm getting `path` using Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker, so it **should** be a real file, but sometimes the FilePicker returns URI instead of a path. For example, if I pick an image from camera it returns a path, and if I pick a file from Downloads, it returns a URI).

Comment: you want to use this code to open internet file url?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. File can be launched using ActionView intent if the 'path ' is a content URI.

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class myClass
    {
        public void OpenFile(string path)
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            if (intent.ResolveActivity(Activity.PackageManager) != null)
                StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

If it is a path, your app must be a `FileProvider` to use this method, as stated here: [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

In this case, use `Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher` because it adds `FileProvider` functionality to your app.